# Uber-api Create user request & book multiple rides for same user

Tags: uber-api

I was going over the API and wondering if I can book multiple rides for same client id? Also, are there any intentions to create a Create Users API?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I was going over the API and wondering if I can book multiple rides for same client id?" -- Yes, you can book multiple rides from the same client ID. This question is slightly different from the title of this thread however which is "book multiple rides for same user", to be clear a user can only take one ride at a time.

"Also, are there any intentions to create a Create Users API?" -- No plans, accounts should be created through Uber.

Hope that helps!